# Why am I getting a keyerror when trying to import the requests module? KeyError: 'requests'

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, keyerror

I don't understand why I am getting a KeyError. When running my code through the idle debugger.The directory with the requests module/folder is added to the PATH. Installing with pip shows that all of the dependencies are installed, and the module shows up when I run pip freeze. I'm not sure what the problem is here... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import requests

def get_btc_price():
    # Make the API call to retrieve the current price of Bitcoin
    response = requests.get(
        "https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/market/orderbook/level2_100?symbol=BTC-USDT"
    )

    # Check if the API call was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Parse the JSON response
        data = response.json()

        # Return the current price of Bitcoin
        return print(float(data["data"]["bids"][0][0]))

    # If the API call was unsuccessful, return 0
    return 0


get_btc_price
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there was a conflict with an old version of Python... I deleted all PATH variables related to Python, then did an uninstall/reinstall of Python and the issue is resolved.